# Reheating Hamburger Helper

Tags: culinary-uses, reheating

When I make Hamburger Helper I always follow the directions exactly and the consistency of the sauce is usually good--not too thick and not too watery--but whenever I reheat the leftovers the sauce practically turns into water and it becomes like a noodle and beef soup. This happens with every flavor. What's weird is I always remember leftover Hamburger Helper being too thick and dry and I needed to add water, but now the complete opposite is happening.

Am I draining the ground beef too much when I cook it? Is there something I should be doing differently? Have the ingredients or recipes changed somehow?

Comment: How are you storing it? In a sealed container while still hot?

Comment: I put it in tupperware after I'm done eating it. It's about room temperature by the time I put it away.

Comment: @Matt, you should put the information from your comment into the question, Comments are more readily deleted and designed to evoke the user to edit more information into their post.

Comment: FYI, putting it away in the fridge uncovered will dry it out a good bit, so it may counter the effect you are seeing.

Comment: How are you reheating it?  If you now have a more powerful microwave, you might be overheating it to the point that the cornstarch breaks down as a thickener

Answer (score 13):

I called General Mills, the makers of Hamburger Helper, and asked if there had been any changes to their recipes in the past 3 years. The representative (Thanks Kathy!) told me that the only recent change happened in 2016 when they stopped using [artificial flavors and colors](https://www.fda.gov/food/ingredientspackaginglabeling/foodadditivesingredients/ucm094211.htm) and switched to an all-natural formula. (see [What does "natural" actually mean?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/54514/what-does-natural-actually-mean))

I also visited the [General Mills website](https://www.generalmills.com/en/Brands/Meals/helper/brand-product-list) and read the ingredients for all of the Hamburger Helper varieties. They are all thickened with cornstarch. Cornstarch does tend to thin out upon reheating, but I have no explanation of what could account for your change in experience (all other factors being the same). Look to what you’re doing differently, and methinks that there’s your answer.